# How do you show cost function per iteration in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been running some linear/logistic regression models recently, and I wanted to know how you can output the cost function for each iteration. One of the parameters in sci-kit LinearRegression is 'maxiter', but in reality you need to see cost vs iteration to find out what this value really needs to be i.e. is the benefit worth the computational time to run more iterations etc

I'm sure I'm missing something but I would have thought there was a method that outputted this information?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One has to understand if there is any iteration (implying computing a cost function) or an analytical exact solution, when fitting any estimator.

**Linear Regression**

In fact, Linear Regression - ie Minimization of the Ordinary Least Square - is not an algorithm but a minimization problem that can be solved using different techniques. And those techniques

Not getting into the details of the statistical part described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/what-algorithm-is-used-in-linear-regression) :

> There are at least three methods used in practice for computing least-squares solutions: the normal equations, QR decomposition, and singular value decomposition.

As far as I got into the details of the codes, it seems that the computational time is involved by getting the analytical exact solution, not iterating over the cost function. But I bet they depend on your system being under-, well- or over-determined, as well as the language and library you are using.

**Logistic Regression**

As Linear Regression, Logistic Regression is a minimization problem that can be solved using different techniques that, for scikit-learn, are : `newton-cg`, `lbfgs`, `liblinear` and `sag`.
As you mentionned, `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` includes the `max_iter` argument, meaning it includes iterations*. Those are controled either because the updated argument *doesn't change anymore* - up to a certain epsilon value - or because it reached the maximum number of iterations.

*As mentionned in the doc, it includes iterations only for some of the solvers

> Useful only for the newton-cg, sag and lbfgs solvers. Maximum number of iterations taken for the solvers to converge.

In fact, each solver involves its own implementation, such as [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/svm/base.py#L766) for the `liblinear` solver.

I would recommand to use the `verbose` argument, maybe equal to `2` or `3` to get the maximum value. Depending on the solver, it might print the cost function error. However, I don't understand how you are planning to use this information.

Another solution might be to code your own solver and print the cost function at each iteration.

---

Curiosity kills cat but I checked the source code of scikit which involves many more.

1. First, `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` use a fit to train its parameters.
2. Then, in the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L402) code of `fit`, they use the [Ordinary Least Square of Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)  ([source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/linalg/linalg.py#L1785-L1943)).
3. Finally, Numpy's Least Square function uses the [function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lapack.dgelsd.html)`scipy.linalg.lapack.dgelsd`, a wrapper to the LAPACK (Linear Algebra PACKage) function `DGELSD` written in Fortran ([source](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/db/d6a/dgelsd_8f_source.html)).

That is to say that getting into the error calculation, if any, is not easy for scikit-learn developers. However, for the various using of `LinearRegression` and many more I had, the trade-off between cost-function and iteration time is well-adressed.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My confusion comes from the fact that you have a parameter that dictates the maximum number of iterations. However, this surely depends largely on how the cost function (assuming there is one for a moment) converges. How would you suggest one assesses if the algorithm has correctly converged to a reasonable value? I think for the most part I just want to be able to see the cost vs iteration (that is displayed frequently, for example, in Andrew Ng's course) to convince myself that the algorithm is doing the correct thing etc.

Comment: Is there any other visualisations or metrics you would recommend to assess your model?

Comment: You're right, I missed the part on `LogisticRegression` which includes `maxiter`. I just edited the answer

Comment: Assessing the model can be made using cross-validation techniques - not the convergence of the cost function. 

The convergence of your estimator, while training, does not assess the quality of your model, and vice-versa! Think about overfitting : the cost-function gets very low while converging, but your model is bad. 
What you might looking for is to compare estimators. In that case, compare them on the cross validation score.

Comment: Thanks for your response again! Much appreciated - I wasn't really intending to use it to assess the quality of the model but to understand how quickly the model converges on a minima. But I guess what you are suggesting is comparing different models through cross validation (using a metric like RMSE or something) instead of looking at which model has the lowest cost value. I guess what I was asking is by knowing the cost function might give you information about whether you should increase the 'maxiter' parameter. Perhaps the default 100 isn't enough, for example?

Comment: Finally, is there anyway to find out the difference between the solvers (linlib/newton-cg etc)? should this be a big consideration when you run the algorithm?

Comment: What you should do is get a cross-validation score with each estimator/solver combinaison. However, depending on your dataset and task, you might consider scikit learn recommandation for the solvers [here](scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

Comment: Thank you for all your guidance :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again... how do you actually output the Verbose data? I have multiple models stored in a dictionary and using the method .verbose just prints the value I chose for 'verbose'. Thanks again

Comment: What value did you choose for `verbose`? Usually, it's an integer, `1`, `2`, maybe  `3`. You can get into the source code to check it out. However, it is not a method but a function argument

Comment: Hi Igor, I did as you suggested but tried 1-3. Unfortunately, nothing actually outputs - should I be using print or something?

Comment: verbose=10, prints cv score generated in each trained model. Just an FYI